# Convert Transitive Function From Python to Racket

Tags: python, racket, relation

I would like to implement this function in Racket. How could I rewrite this function in Racket?

**My CODE IN PYTHON**

```python
# function to check transitive relation
def is_transitive(relation):
    # for all (a, b) and (b, c) in Relation ; (a, c) must belong to Relation
    for a,b in relation:
        for c,d in relation:
            if b == c and ((a,d) not in relation):
                return False
    return True
```

`transitive?` takes a list of pairs as its only input. That list of pairs represents a binary relation. The function should return `#t` if that binary relation is transitive, as illustrated below.

```
> (transitive? '((1 2) (2 3) (1 3)))
#t
> (transitive? '((1 3) (1 2) (2 3)))
#t
> (transitive? '((1 2) (2 3)))
#f
> (transitive? '((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2) (3 3)))
#t
> (transitive? '((1 2) (3 3) (2 2) (2 1) (1 1)))
#t
> (transitive? '((2 3) (3 3) (1 2) (1 1)))
#f
```

Here is what I have in Racket so far:

```scheme
(define (get-all-relations-of x set)
  (if (null? set)
      '()
      (if (equal? x (car (car set)))
          (cons (cdr (car set))
                (get-all-relations-of x (cdr set)))
          (get-all-relations-of x (cdr set)))))
    
(define (exist-relation? r set)
  (if (null? set)
      #f
      (if (equal? r (car set))
          #t
          (exist-relation? r (cdr set)))))
    
(define (exist-all-transitive-relations-of? x r set)
  (if (null? r)
      #t
      (if (not (exist-relation? (cons x (car r)) set))
          #f
          (exist-all-transitive-relations-of? x (cdr r) set))))
    
(define (transitive? set)
  (if (null? set)
      #t
      (if (and (not (null? (get-all-relations-of (cdr (car set)) set)))
               (not (exist-all-transitive-relations-of?
                     (car (car set))
                     (get-all-relations-of (cdr (car set)) set)
                     set)))
          #f
          (transitive? (cdr set)))))
```

It only works when(exist-all-transitive-relations-of? x r set) is true.

Here is my output :

```
>(exist-all-transitive-relations-of? 1 '(2 5 6) '((1 2) (1 5) (6 8)))))
> #t
>(define (transitive? '((1 2) (2 6)))
> #f
>(define (transitive? '((1 2) (2 6)(2 7)(1 7)))
> #f
>(define (transitive? '((1 2) (2 6)(2 7)(1 7)(1 6)))
> #t
```

How can I modify my code? so that I don't have to test if (define (exist-all-transitive-relations-of? x r set) is true separately

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Any Racket code you care to share?

Comment: Just added my code^

Comment: Does the Racket code work? If not, what is going wrong? Have you checked `get-all-relations-of`, `exist-relation?`, and `exist-all-transitive-relations-of?` with test cases to find out if they are behaving as expected?

Comment: the code works only if I test for exist-all-transitive-relations-of? first

Comment: What is the expected output for your given examples? Because the python code gives the exact same output for all of your examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few comments on the racket you have here:

When you do:

```
(if (condition) #f (else))
```

you can use short circuiting to convert it to

```
(and (condition) (else))
```

Similar for

```
(if (condition) #t (else))
```

do

```
(or (condition) (else))
```

Finally, it is very important to consider the existing list abstractions when thinking about replacing for loops in python. In this case you are taking a list and condensing it down into one piece of data specifically a boolean if the property breaks for one member. Therefore, you should use `andmap` which will drastically reduce your code:

```
(define (transitive? set)
  (andmap (lambda (x) (andmap (lambda (y)
       (local [(define a (first x))
               (define b (second x))
               (define c (first y))
               (define d (second y))]
       (not (and (= b c) (not (member `(,a ,d) set)))))) set)) set))
```

Notes: `(,a ,d)` can be replaced with `(list a d)` (no quasiquote) if you want. And `first` and `second` with `car` and `cadr`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed = to equal? so that it does not only work for numbers.

Comment: ` is quasiquote which works like ' but quote makes all of the elements of a list into symbols (thus you would get `(list 'a 'd)`) and that would cause `a` and `d` to not get replaced. Quasiquote allows you to unquote ( `,` ) within and effectively "eliminates" that quasiquote. So it expands to "(list ```,a ```,d)" which expands to `(list a d)` and `a` and `d` are replaced. Here is the HTDP on it https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/i2-3.html